# How i show image from store firebase using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I try to develop chatbot by using Fulfillment(code using Node.js) on Dialogflow and connect with Firebase.

I stored an image in Firestore.
I want to show that image, but I'm a newbie for Node.js, Firebase and I have no idea.

I already read doc for upload/download URL from Firestore, but I still don't understand concept of it.

Would you explain to me about how or wording to search?

[I want to show this image from storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGU3y.png)

[Error: storage is not defined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DVNQ.png)

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); 

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = 
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

var httpsReference = storage.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jenniebot2-94120.appspot.com/o/images%2FPicture5.jpg?alt=media&token=c853681b-2a72-45e4-ac7a-016f62396fa8');

function bodyMassIndex(agent) {
  let weight = 80;
  let height = 170/100;
  let bmi = (weight / (height * height)).toFixed(2);
  let result = "none";

  if (bmi < 18.5) {
    result = "xs";
  } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 22.9) {
    result = "s";
  } else if (bmi >= 23 && bmi <= 24.9) {
    result = "m";
  } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29.9) {
    result = "l";
  } else if (bmi > 30) {
    result = "xl";
  }

  return admin.firestore().collection('bmi').doc(result).get()
  .then(doc => {agent.add(doc.data().description);});
}
function welcome(agent) {
agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
}
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Bmi', bodyMassIndex);    
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Node js is a backend language and firebase also, although it is javascript, the better choice is with js focused on frontend, pure javascript, Vue, React, etc.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @memoadian Thank you. javascript is good. It a great idea I will try it. Previously, I try with Node.js because my Chatbot integrated with message mobile application, Dialogflow already has Node.js libraries and I already some coding function.

Comment: Without seeing some of your code of what you tried, it is somewhat difficult to help you. For example, how are you storing the image in firestore? How are you doing the fulfillment in Dialogflow? Without repeating the existing documentation, you don't give us much to start with to help you. Please update your question to show us what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: @Prisoner Sorry. I already edited on my question(add code, images).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code, both logical and syntactical.

The line

```
var httpsReference = storage.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jenniebot2-94120.appspot.com/o/images%2FPicture5.jpg?alt=media&token=c853681b-2a72-45e4-ac7a-016f62396fa8');
```

doesn't make any sense. You don't define `storage` before this, and you don't use `httpsReference` anywhere later.

Given the URL, it looks like this file is stored in [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage/), which is a good place to store and access files. This is very different than [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) database, which is good at storing semi-structured data documents.

If this is true, then you would create `storage` with something like

```
var storage = admin.storage();
```

which says to get the [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage) service object from the firebase admin.

But if this is true - then it isn't clear what you plan to *do* with the `httpsReference` object now that you have it.

If all you want to do is show the image at that URL as part of the Dialogflow response, then you don't need to go through the API - you can just access it through the URL. If you load that URL in a browser right now, you'll see the image.

It isn't clear if you want this as an image in a Card or as a stand-alone image in the response, but either way, you just need to use the URL. Perhaps something like

```
var card = new Card();
card.addTitle("BMI Chart");
card.addImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jenniebot2-94120.appspot.com/o/images%2FPicture5.jpg?alt=media&token=c853681b-2a72-45e4-ac7a-016f62396fa8");
agent.add(card);
```

or

```
const {Image} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var image = new Image();
image.setImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jenniebot2-94120.appspot.com/o/images%2FPicture5.jpg?alt=media&token=c853681b-2a72-45e4-ac7a-016f62396fa8");
agent.add(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem is so easy. I just take it harder than it should be. Just use URL form Firebase Storage and put it in LINE API(.JSON). then use dialogflow for the response.

```
{
  "type": "image",
  "originalContentUrl": "/URL",
  "previewImageUrl": "/URL",
  "animated": false
}
```